# Django Admin: How to dynamically populate suggested ForeignKey values based on another ForeignKey choice?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Is there a way to dynamically change the values displayed in SelectFields for ForeignKeys in Django Admin? Without having to write some custom JS that does it.

Say, I have two models: **Topic** and **AreaOfDiscussion**.
Topic has an area of discussion, as in

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(AreaOfDiscussion, null=False)
```

Now I'm adding a **Lecture** model, which must have both a topic and an area.

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
     area = models.ForeignKey(AreaOfDiscussion, null=False)
     topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, null=False)
```

I want the user (of the admin panel) to be able to choose an area first, then based on the choice, give him/her a list of available Topics for the chosen Area. Is this achievable?

Comment: No, it is not achievable without writing some custom JS.

Comment: Why does the `Lecture` model need both an area and a topic? Won't the area already imply a topic?

Comment: It's simply an example and not the actual code. Of course a topic would imply an area, but topics can have the same name, e.g. "Introduction". That would make it inconvenient if not impossible for the user to understand what he/she's doing.

Comment: The other purpose of saving "duplicating" the field (which essentially this is) in this model is faster db lookups

Answer (score 1):

You can use `django-smart-selects` package:
https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set topic = models.Fk(..., null=True)

```
class AdminLecture(admin.ModelAdmin):
    object = None

    def get_object(self, request, object_id):
        self.object = super(AdminLecture, self).get_object(request, object_id)
        return self.object

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):

        if self.object and db_field.name == 'topic':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Topic.objects.filter(area=self.object.area)
        return super(AdminLecture, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

then push  **save and cotinue edit**

Comment: Seems like this will only be called when the page is initially rendered, not any time the user changes selected value, but thanks )

Comment: Every time, when user change -  you needs refresh page, another way - js and ajax ( Ludwik Trammer pointed )

Comment: Yes, that's what it looked like, so I asked whether it was possible without some JS - couldn't find it in the docs